# How to convert excel cell content to double

Tags: c#

I need to import some stuff from `Excel` and I just started to browse around but I cannot convert `.Value2` to `double` (in the end I want the excel content in a custom list). Here is what I have done:

```
Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"D:\Test.xls");
Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
Excel.Range range;
range = xlWorksheet.get_Range("A20:V20000", Missing.Value);
int rowcount = range.Rows.Count;
double testsum = 0;

for (int i=1; i<=rowcount;i++)
{
   try
   {
      testsum += double.Parse(range.Cells[i, 2].Value2.ToString());
   }
   catch 
   { 
      break; 
   }
}
Console.WriteLine(testsum.ToString());
Console.ReadKey();
```

which returns zero even though column is populated. 
also this returns zero:

```
testsum += range.Cells[i, 2].Value2;
```

In general what is the advantage/ disadvantages of using `Interop` over `OleDB`? I know exactly the column format and start row, just not the number of rows.

```
Console.WriteLine(range.Cells[i, 2].Value2.ToString());
```

Writes the desired value to the console.

Comment: When debug what is range.Cells[i, 2].Value2 itself?

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the value of `range.Cells[i, 2].Value2.ToString()` before you try to parse it?  What is it?

Comment: yes, it just returns the value in the cell if I write it to the console, e.g. 46,5

Comment: Is it because it is a com object?

Comment: @nik is that 46 (comma) 5 or 46 (period) 5?

Comment: @Grant: continue still returns zero

Comment: Using OleDb you avoid a lot of the issues with trying to parse the values that come back as COM objects.  Remember that in Visual Studio, the Quick Watch window and the Debug windows do some magic to make it more readable, so what you see may not always reflect exactly what the object is.

Comment: @nik just couple points, I would not have try/catch in a loop and I would not have a catch that doesn't tell me what the exception is. I would have the initialization as 0.0 for the double because it is confusing look at as a int value.

Comment: @Bit: sure. I only used try catch because an if null didnt work and as said in the q I dont know how many rows so I want it to break at the last row. But if I cant even do a simple sum over the data I might as well stop here and try OleDB

Comment: @MauriceReeves: I think you are right, I will try OLeDB

Comment: I get values when using the double.TryParse Method ... can´t find the mistake

Comment: @nik the for loop will stop on the last row, you do not need to break for it. You can use a string.IsNullOrEmpty if statement to check for a value on range.Cells[i, 2].Value2.ToString().

Comment: I would look into using SpireXLS for .NET.  That product saved me a ton of time when parsing out spreadsheet data.  You would create a model for the type of data that you are trying to read from a given address range it it would handle the conversion for you.  There is a free version as well as a commercial version so you can give it a shot.

https://www.e-iceblue.com/News/spirexls-10120.html